# How to fix syntax highlighting with ES6/ES2015 string interpolation?

Tags: javascript, vim

My vim screws up the highlighting with string interpolation:

[image: highlighting error]

How do I update the JS grammar to fix it? Does it have to do with my color theme or with vim/macvim itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install this package: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=5230

There is a description on the page to help you install it.

This is their github repo: https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate

Comment: Thanks. Do you know of one that doesn't require VimSnip? I don't need an extra plugin or the snippets

Comment: Why not? I'd suggest to use Vundle, it is very easy to install and use.

Comment: @springloaded you can also change/add your own  js syntax file, in order to make it work as you expected. In this way, no extra plugin is needed.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

Install [`Plugin 'mxw/vim-jsx'`](https://github.com/mxw/vim-jsx)

Then put this in your `.vimrc`

```
" This allows jsx syntax highlighting in js files
let g:jsx_ext_required = 0
```

If you use vundle, just put this `Plugin 'mxw/vim-jsx'` and the above lines in your `.vimrc` and run `:PluginInstall`